# Licorice flavor Beer

Tags: flavor

I'm thinking about making beer with Licorice flavor as I like the taste of Licorice.  I'm thinking some dark beer would be a good candidate a Stout maybe or some ale.  I'm thinking some black Licorice sticks during <del>the fermentation</del> boil and maybe Licorice Root as well.  Does anybody have experience with this ?

Comment: Star anise also has a licorice flavour. I've used it in meads, it flavours it nicely. You could also use anise seed.

Comment: And there is http://www.austinhomebrew.com/product_info.php?products_id=494

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I would make that comment an answer, as I agree that would be the way to go.

Comment: @hartski: I left it as a comment because I've never tried it with beer.

Comment: I have a Russian Imperial that used a large amount of various dark crystal malts.  It's primary flavor is licorice/anise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a honey licorice porter a couple of years ago, and it came out pretty well. I used dried licorice root at the end of the boil, which my LHBS sells. Like this:
http://morebeer.com/view_product/15607//Licorice_Root_2_oz

The licorice flavor was subtle but noticeable, and pleasant against the malt base and roastiness in the porter. Here's the recipe, 5gal extract-based:

- 7.0 lb liquid amber malt extract
- 1.0 lb Crystal 80L malt
- 0.5 lb Chocolate malt
- 0.5 lb Black patent malt
- 3.0 lb Clover honey
- 1.0 oz Perle @ 60 min
- 0.5 oz Fuggles @ 30 min
- 0.5 oz Fuggles @ 5 min
- 0.5 oz Dried licorice root
- Wyeast 1084

Steep grains, add extract, and boil for 60 min, adding hops as directed. At flameout stir in honey, then add licorice root in a mesh bag and let steep for 30 minutes while wort cools.

OG around 1.070. FG around 1.015-1.020.

Comment: Did you add the licorice during the boil or in secondary?

Comment: At the end of boil. I found the recipe! Stuffed into the back of an old notebook. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option to steeping to attain the licorice flavors would be to prime with an anise based liqueur.  I've had success with a few fruit flavored beers and liqueur priming.  You'd want to find something with a lower abv though such as galliano/anisette as the higher test stuff like sambuca/ouzo won't have the sugar content.